How to change the text value of the build number and windows version on the bottom right of a Windows 11 screen?
How to change the text value of the place where the build number and windows version on the bottom right of a Windows 11 screen is shown?
Via powershell or another scripting option.
Thanks

Appending a question mark to a statement doesn't magically turn it into a question.

@IInspectable lol, could you help me with ma english? I am foreignar.

Your other posts appear to not suffer from the English disability to such a degree. Your question is off topic.

We help you to fix an issue with your programming code. So in order to provide an on topic question, for us to assist with, you need to: 1. Find out where the displayed information is located. 2. Choose a programming/scripting language. 3. Attempt the code yourself. 4. Submit that code together with an explanation of the problem it exhibits, (including all reasonable debugging information). Until that time, it is unlikely that your question closure will be overturned.

Well that is the question, I know there is a flag in Regedit one can turn the display of the string on and off. However I don't know where the value is stored and if it can be modified via Powershell or BAT. Hence the question.

I have a valid Windows 11 box. Just want to know if it's possible to customize the message that is displayed there. I want to put my own strings there, not the build number or windows version.

Here is what I am trying to do. I have specs on the box that change randomly based on other settings. I would like to display those specs or the results of the change to those specs in a small message there every time they change. Kind of like a status of info I find to be critical for my needs.
